# Visualisations of UIKit View Classes and Other iPhone widgets

Tags: iphone

I'm slowly working through the [iPhone Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW1) and although it's been great I was wondering if anybody has seen any resources that match class names/widgets with a visualisation/diagram.

For example when I'm reading about Containers and UITableView's it'd be very helpful if I could see what the widget actually looked like. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you get started with development, the UICatalog example project can also be very helpful. It shows each type of UI element (buttons, sliders, images, etc...) and you can look at the source to get a feeling for how it is used.

Answer (score 2):

You can see how the controls look like in interface builder. You won't see the exact classname, but it's pretty straightforward. A progress bar is a UIProgressBarView, a button is a UIButton, etc.